# Create multiple directories based on files found

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to create directories to store image sequences based on a 'find' command.

Let's say there are 2 image sequences in different locations within the 'test' directory

```
test_123.####.dpx
test_abc.####.dpx
```

I would run something like:

```
testDir=$(find /Users/Tim/test/ -type f -name "test*.dpx")
```

and it would return all of the files as listed above.

What I would like to do is create two directories named test_123 and test_abc.

```
mkdir /Users/Tim/test/scan/${testDir:t:r:r}
```

If I run this then it will only create one directory, presumably based on the first result.

How would I be able to make this work to create directories that share the same base name for an unlimited number of results? (not just two as in the case of this example).

Comment: You could store the list of the matching directories into an array and then loop through this array and process each entry accordingly. In your colde, `testDir` is simply a string holding the complete output of the `find` command. Not a very useful data structure to process its constituents....

Answer (score 0):

if it's not important that it's done in zsh, you could just do it in python like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
x = 0
y = 0
if input(f"{os.getcwd()} is current working dir. press y to continue \n") == "y":
    for file in os.listdir(): # get files in current folder
        split = file.split(".") # split by .
        if len(split) > 1: # only files with more than one . are considered
            if split[0] not in os.listdir(): # if the folder it fits doesn't exist
                os.mkdir(split[0])  # make the folder
                print(f"made new folder {split[0]}")
                y = y + 1
            os.rename(file, os.path.join(split[0],file)) # then move it there - OS agnostic path generated!
            x = x + 1
print(f"moved {x} files to {y} folders!")
```

I added a check before it runs, just to prevent random people who find this from wreaking havoc. The `if len(split) > 1:` should also prevent some accidents by making sure it's only files with at least 2 dots that are moved, as that's an unusual naming scheme.